# Вывод элемента из массива объектов

Tags: java, массивы, вывод

Как выполнить вывод всех элементов из ячейки массива объектов?
Допустим, если мне нужно имя, то пишу arr[0].name. А как вывести все, что есть в данной ячейке, а не только имя? а то получаю вывод ссылки

Comment: Или мне через запятую всех элементов вывод делать...

Comment: переопределить метод `toString()` и там отправить на вывод всё что вам нужно

Comment: System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr))